# I washed my cat with human shampoo

Tags: cats

I recently washed my cat with human shampoo to combat the fleas he has. I know the fleas and the flea medicine are not the problem so its most likely the shampoo (after reviewing other sources). What can I do to help my cat as he is losing hair very quickly since I bathed him?

Comment: The ingredients of human shampoo and pet shampoo are different. Maybe you should stop bath him with it. Have you taken him to see a vet?

Comment: A bad flea infestation can cause hair loss, an allergy to something in the shampoo could possibly be a cause, and illness or stress (including potentially the stress of being bathed if the cat has to be forcefully restrained to accomplish it) could also cause excessive shedding.  You should probably start with a call to a vet to rule out allergy or disease.